# How can I view my Windows 7 firewall settings?

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I am using a work laptop and can't seem to locate my firewall settings.  I go to Control Panel > System and Security and I do not see firewall settings anywhere.  Could there be some policy that is hiding this option?  Is there any other way to locate what firewall I am using?

Answer (score 0):

Open the [Action Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-Action-Center) to check what AV, firewall etc. you're using.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: I seem to be unable to locate the Action Center.  It's as if it's not even there.  Any specifics on where this is?  I am looking in `Control Panel\System and Security`.  When I search the Start Menu for "action center", nothing comes up.

Comment: 1. Open the **Local Group Policy Editor** (`Start / Type "Edit group policy"` or `Run / gpedit.msc`). 2. Confirm that under `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel` both **Hide specified Control Panel items** and **Show only specified Control Panel items** are set to *Not configured*. 3. Confirm that under `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar`, the **Remove the Action Center icon** setting is also set to *Not configured*.

Comment: So I changed all items you mentioned from `Enabled` to `Not Configured`.  Still, I do not see Action Center or Windows Firewall in control panel under System and Security.  Edit:  Does this call for a reboot?

Comment: Ah, so they *were* enabled. Yeah, you should see if the options show up after a reboot. Also, why exactly do you want to know what firewall they've installed for you?

Answer (score -1):

- GOTO to run, type services.msc.
- find windows firewall.
- turn it on, if its not started.
- Now, check to see if you can find it inside system security.

  Chances are that, you are in standard type of account and not in administrator account.

Comment: That tells me whether or not the Windows firewall is running, but it does not tell me what firewall I am using (eg, Windows, third-party firewall, etc).